# Vuex: set state from getter in another module

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have two modules in my store:

```
modules: {
  topojsonStore: topojsonStore,
  layersStore: layersStore,
}
```

Both are namespaced.
In topojsonStore, I have a state and a getter:

```
state: {
  municipalityTopo: {...},
},

getters: {
  getMunicipalityTopo: state => state.municipalityTopo,
}
```

In the state of my layersStore, I want to reference this getter and store it in inside an object, something like this:

```
state: {
  municipalityLayer: 
    { topo: <rootState>.topoJsonStore.getMunicipalityTopo,
      data: {...},
      type: 'polygon' }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the reason? Do you want to make use of it in any action of your `layersStore` ?

Comment: Same question as @VamsiKrishna. Maybe you will find more information on https://forum.vuejs.org/t/get-state-from-another-module-does-any-one-have-the-same-problem/4380

Comment: The idea is to have various layers with different topojson geometries. The user can select different datasets associated with these geometries to visualize data using d3. The topojson, however, is loaded when the vue app is started. I felt like it would be cleaner to have all the logic associated with this loading process in a separate store. I could, of course, all put it in the same store but was just wondering if this could also work. The topojson will be read only, the user will only change other attributes in each layer, like toggling the visibility or something